# Save The World / Battle Royale skins; are they interchangeable?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale, fortnite-save-the-world

I recently bought the Save The World standard edition and I was curious as to whether or not the heroes earned there are playable in Battle Royale.

For instance, I just started grinding out some of the event missions and there is a statue-looking hero (don't recall his name, but you probably know what I am talking about) that can be earned and I have seen this skin in videos of Battle Royale.

Obviously, they bought the skin in the Battle Royale shop when I saw it, but I was wondering if I got this skin in STW would I have it in Battle Royale as well? Only asking since when getting the twitch prime pack I had been given the two skins in both gamemodes.

Comment: I have both modes and haven't gotten any skins shared across both modes as far as I can see. Will add an answer though if I get time to check this. FWIW though you have characters in STW but skins in BR so I guess not.

Comment: I didn't think Save the World has skins.  Instead, it has separate heroes with different abilities, each of which has a specific skin.

Answer (score 2):

No, the skins you have in BR are not interchangable between the skins you get in STW.

The only thing that carries over between both game modes are:

- V-Bucks
- Banner Icons

Comment: Twitch Prime skins - in a sense - are not carried over since you essentially "earn" them on both gamemodes.

Answer (score 1):

Save The World "Skins" are not interchangeable, and they are also not skins. In Save The World, the skins are actually different heroes with different abilities and stats. A lot of Heros in save the world will come into Battle Royale which you can buy for V-Bucks in the battle royale shop.

Answer (score 0):

Skins are not interchangeable; in save-the-world, your skins are pulled into classes, while in Battle Royale it’s just rarities.